# Write output file to a privileged directory - from an executable which is run as a non-privileged user

Tags: bash, files, permissions, io-redirection

I want to execute the program `bu` as user `backup` and I want the output file at location `/mnt/nas1/`. However, this location can only be written by `sysred`, and `bu` has no command line options whatsoever to output to stdout, only to a file. How do I write the output file to the target location, without temporarily saving the whole file to an interim directory? Here's a sample command:

```
sysred@host1:~> sudo -u backup bu -f /mnt/nas1/backup.zip
```

This fails of course, because `backup` has no access to the target folder.

```
sysred@host1:~> sudo -u backup bu -f /dev/stdout > /mnt/nas1/backup.zip
```

This also fails, I assume because the current `/dev/stdout` belongs to `sysred`.

The next thing I tried was using named pipes. As user `sysred`:

```
mkfifo -m 0777 /tmp/backup
cat /tmp/backup > /mnt/nas1/backup.zip &
sudo -u backup bu -f /tmp/backup
```

Error message: `Failed to create /tmp/backup: zip: not a valid zip file`. Any other ideas?

Comment: pipe it into `sudo tee /mnt/nas1/backup.zip >/dev/null` ?

Comment: @steve I could not get `bu` to write to stdout.

Comment: ok, maybe add more detail about what `bu` is ?  is it some widely used tool or something unique to your environment, in which case maybe change it to support writing to stdout ?

Comment: What's the ownership, group, & permissions of `/mnt/nas1`? `ls -ld /mnt/nas1`. Does it (can it be changed) allow group `rw`? Can the `backup` user be added to the group of `/mnt/nas1`? `sudo adduser backup $( stat --format="%G" /mnt/nas1 )`.

Comment: Could you add a subdirectory of `/mnt/nas1` that `backup` owns and can write to?

Comment: @waltinator That was the hint! It were indeed the write permissions of the directory. I've had silently assumed that it is one of our typical CIFS shares, where everything is `0777`, but it was actually NFS. If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.